# In Mule , how to check two files exists or not

Tags: file, mule

how to check two files exists or not. I mean two file patterns i.e. File* and errorFile*, if they exist then trigger a flow.

I am using File Connector (Mule 3.8) to start with one file with pattern File*, after that, I want to check for the second file exist i.e. errorFile* to continue with my process.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should elaborate more about what you have attempted till now.

Following steps should help you go through:

1. Get a list of files at the location using 'List' element of the SFTP connector (Mule 4).
2. Parse this list and if you find the required filename, set a flow variable to a certain value.
3. Make use of the Choice element to trigger a subflow based on the value of the variable.

Comment: more elabrorated

Comment: small correction: there are only variables in Mule 4. Flow variables exist only in Mule 3.